# whats wrong with the .htaccess / apache settings?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following in my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)?$ index.php?url=$1/ [PT]
```

On one machine (ubuntu, apache) it works perfectly well, on another machine (ubuntu, apache) it  generates an Internal Server Error. If I comment the 3 lines out the server works.

The server configuration is

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Any hint to solve the problem (appearently an error in the settings?) I am feeling kind of stupid :-(

Comment: Have you checked whether the server has `mod_rewrite` enabled? `httpd -L` will tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is mod_rewrite enabled on the 2nd server?

Run the following two commands in the terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you very, very much, Nealio and Jack!! [cant vote up, sorry]